# Ormlite performance

Tags: java, android, performance, ormlite

I am testing the performance of Ormlite and I get impressed about it.
How is possible that `testORMLITE_jobget()` is more fast then `testORMLITE_getcursor()`?

```
public void testORMLITE_jobget() throws SQLException {
    Dao<Job, Integer> dao = dbhelper.getJobDao();
    List<Job> jobs = dao.queryForAll();
    for (Job job : jobs) {
        Log.i("OrmLite", job.getName());
    }
    dbhelper.close();
}

public void testORMLITE_getcursor() throws SQLException {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from job", null);
    if (c.moveToFirst())
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Log.i("Cursor", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
        }
    c.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Second question: Do I am deleting correctly the foreign collection in this way?

```
public void testORMLITE_jobdelete() throws SQLException{
    Job j = dbhelper.getJobDao().queryForId(5);
    dbhelper.getTagDao().delete(j.tags);
    dbhelper.getJobDao().delete(j);
}
```

Comment: First off, those are terrible method names.  `testOrmliteJobDelete()` would be better. :-)

Comment: What performance are you getting from those 2 calls?  Is it repeatable?

Comment: testORMLITE_jobget() = 1.3ms - testORMLITE_getcursor() = 6.4ms

Comment: I would have though that ORMLite would be slower.  No idea why the cursor is slower.